# CE1.9.2 - Filter Orders collection on hasInvoices()

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I've separated this from [another question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112998/ce1-9-2-testing-resource-iterator-in-plain-php-file) I had asked before. How would I be able to filter the `sales/order` collection on `hasInvoices()` **and** ensure that there is no balance due to pay? I'd like to avoid doing this in the iteration step and hopefully save performance hits.

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('complete','processing'));

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    if (($order->hasInvoices()) && ($order->getTotalDue() == 0)) {
        echo $order->getIncrementId() . "\n";
    }
}
```

The code above does work, but I think it would be much better to iterate through an already filtered collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Filter by getTotalDue()

To filter by "total due" you have to calculate it with SQL. The method is

```
public function getTotalDue()
{
    $total = $this->getGrandTotal()-$this->getTotalPaid();
    $total = Mage::app()->getStore($this->getStoreId())->roundPrice($total);
    return max($total, 0);
}
```

In SQL `getTotalDue() == 0` would be

```
GREATEST(grand_total - total_paid, 0) = 0
```

You can use arbitrary SQL expressions in `addAttributeToFilter` with `Zend_Db_Expr`, as long as the format is *$attribute $operator $expression*.

So we need to rearrange the equation:

```
    GREATEST(grand_total - total_paid, 0) = 0
<=> grand_total - total_paid <= 0
<=> grand_total <= total_paid
```

This results in the following PHP code:

```
$orders->addAttributeToFilter(
    'grand_total',
    ['lteq' => new Zend_Db_Expr('total_paid')]
);
```

---

### Filter by hasInvoices()

Then join the invoice table using `INNER JOIN` to restrict your collection to orders that have at least one invoice:

```
$orders->join('sales/invoice', 'order_id=main_table.entity_id', []);
```

Comment: This looks so much neater than the method I settled on (direct SQL Query):
`SELECT 'increment_id', 'status', 'total_due' FROM 'sales_flat_order' WHERE ('status' IN ("processing", "complete")) AND ('total_invoiced' IS NOT NULL) AND ('total_due' = 0) AND ('total_paid' IS NOT NULL)`. Thanks fschmengler!